# Arduino Yun: linker error openssl

Tags: c++, c, ssl, linker

I'm trying to compile my security extension on Arduino Yun.

In more detail when i'm trying to link my object files with ssl and crypto library:

```
gcc -O1 -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -shared -fPIC -o output_https.so  output_https.c httpd.lo security.o -lcrypto -lssl
```

They come out these messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
```

Arduino Yun has OpenWRT SO, and I suppose that supports Openssl C library, indeed there are installed `libopenssl` and `openssl-util`. Openssl header files there are too

I don't know where I'm wrong, it seems that the linker `ld` can't find the libraries.

Comment: Make sure the library include path does include the directories where those two libraries are.

Comment: I used `whereis` to find "ssl" and "crypto", then I've added the option -L but doesn't work...this is strange. May be that in Arduino Yun there are the header files, but not the object files to link?